# Extrapolate and download from xml images asp link in WooCommerce

Tags: php, xml, woocommerce, soap, wsdl

we have output XMLs from SOAP, which we need to download to a folder with the same filename that we find in the XML. I file IMG hanno un accesskey:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TableResult>
  <Product>
    <FDI_0843>https://ws.farmadati.it/WS_DOC/GetDoc.aspx?accesskey=xxxxxxx&tipodoc=TE009&nomefile=001536.jpg</FDI_0843>
    <FDI_0840>908872245</FDI_0840>
  </Product>
<Product>
    <FDI_0843>https://ws.farmadati.it/WS_DOC/GetDoc.aspx?accesskey=xxxxxxx&tipodoc=TE009&nomefile=005075.jpg</FDI_0843>
    <FDI_0840>908057906</FDI_0840>
  </Product>
```

How can we create a script to download these images in Woocommerce or in a folder in our FTP?
Thank you for those who will respond

Comment: `DOMDocument` allows you to access the XML and you can then use `getElementsByTagName` to select all the `FDI_0843` nodes. Once you have that nodelist you iterate through them and use `file_put_contents` and `file_get_contents` to save each file to disk

Comment: The above XML however will not parse correctly because of the `&` in the URLS. To ensure that the XML does parse these urls should be within `cdata` sections - either that or you have added the urldecoded version of the XML where these urls are actually url encoded  originally and the ampersands are represented by `&amp;`??

Comment: Thank you @professor-abronsius for the response. Do you have a chance to give an example of code? We are just starting to enter this world. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the URLS within the XML file are protected the following cannot be tested fully but you can try like this, note that the XML as been modified slightly

```
$xmlstring='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TableResult>
    <Product>
        <FDI_0843>https://ws.farmadati.it/WS_DOC/GetDoc.aspx?accesskey=0123BFJ-652e56b0beCad9CBe1c375daCa9A089D35Aab280c&amp;tipodoc=TE009T&amp;nomefile=001536.jpg</FDI_0843>
        <FDI_0840>908872245</FDI_0840>
    </Product>
    <Product>
        <FDI_0843>https://ws.farmadati.it/WS_DOC/GetDoc.aspx?accesskey=0223BFJ-652e56b0beCad9CBe1c375daCa9A089D35Aab280c&amp;tipodoc=TE009X&amp;nomefile=005075.jpg</FDI_0843>
        <FDI_0840>908057906</FDI_0840>
    </Product>
</TableResult>';
            
/**************************************************
    Determine where you will save files to
    and amend this path as necessary. Currently
    this creates a new directory under the current
    working directory if it does not exist.
*/
$save_directory=__DIR__ . '\\save_images_here';
if( !file_exists( $save_directory ) ) {
    mkdir( $save_directory, 0777, true );
}

/*******************************************
    Create the DOMDocument instance & load
    the XML string ( or file )
    
    Query the DOM to find all relevant nodes
    and process that nodelist to extract 
    name of file.
    
    Note in the xml string the ampersand
    is encoded as HTML entity!
*/
libxml_use_internal_errors( true );
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->validateOnParse=false;
$dom->strictErrorChecking=false;
$dom->recover=true;
$dom->loadXML( $xmlstring );
libxml_clear_errors();
/*
    Find all nodes - FDI_0843
*/
$col=$dom->getElementsByTagName('FDI_0843');
if( $col && $col->length > 0 ){
    foreach( $col as $node ){
        # decode the value held by the node
        $url=urldecode( $node->nodeValue );
        
        # extract the querystring
        $querystring=parse_url( $url, PHP_URL_QUERY );
        
        # parse the querystring
        parse_str( $querystring, $output );
        $nomefile=$output['nomefile'];
        
        # create new filepath, download and save target file
        $filepath=sprintf('%s\\%s',$save_directory,$nomefile);
        $filedata=file_get_contents( $url );
        file_put_contents( $filepath, $filedata );# error here ~ had arguments back to front
        
        #... next
    }
}
```

Comment: I had made a mistake with the argument order of `file_put_contents` ~ made a correction above and seems OK.

Comment: thank you very much! You have given me an important help... Last thing, but is it possible to put an xml url in the variable "$xmlstring=" instead of the actual code?

Comment: `"is it possible to put an xml url in the variable '$xmlstring=' instead of the actual code?"` - do you mean a filepath so that DOMDocument can read the XML or is the variable the actual SOAP response? Either way you can either read a file (using `load($xmlfilepath)` or `loadXML($str)`